# C++/MySQL Connector - CDK Error: Failed string conversion

Tags: c++, mysql

When I try to execute the following code:

```
struct  MySQLConnectionInfo
    {
         MySQLConnectionInfo(Config& config, const std::string& configDatabase);
        std::string host;
        std::string mysqlUser;
        std::string mysqlPassword;
        std::string mysqlDatabase;
        std::string mysqlPort;
        std::string ssl;
    };

void MySQLConnection::Connect(MySQLConnectionInfo &mySqlConnectionInfo) {
    try {
        //* Create a connection *//*
        Session sess(mySqlConnectionInfo.host, mySqlConnectionInfo.mysqlPort, mySqlConnectionInfo.mysqlUser, mySqlConnectionInfo.mysqlPassword);
        sess.getSchema(mySqlConnectionInfo.mysqlDatabase);
    }
    catch (const Error &err)
    {
        cout << "MySQL Connection Error: " << err << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
The following error occurred: CDK Error: Failed string conversion

Process finished with exit code
```

What is this `CDK Error: Failed string conversion` and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you building in Debug or Release mode? The libraries are in Release mode, so Debug won't work at the moment. Change it to Release mode and it will work.